# Ignoring PHP error, while still printing a custom error message

Tags: php, error-handling

So:

```
@fopen($file);
```

Ignores any errors and continues

```
fopen($file) or die("Unable to retrieve file");
```

Ignores error, kills program and prints a custom message

Is there an easy way to ignore errors from a function, print a custom error message and not kill the program?

Comment: If you properly configure [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), you can spare the @ operator while you maintain compatibility with displaying errors (you should only do while developing - if at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically:

```
if (!($fp = @fopen($file))) echo "Unable to retrieve file";
```

or using your way (which discards file handle):

```
@fopen($file) or printf("Unable to retrieve file");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Exceptions:

```
try {
   fopen($file);
} catch(Exception $e) {
   /* whatever you want to do in case of an error */
}
```

More information at http://php.net/manual/language.exceptions.php

Comment: fopen doesn't raise Exceptions.

Comment: It does, once you add appropriate handler:
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Answer (score 2):

**slosd**'s way won't work. **fopen** doesn't throw an exception. You should thow it manually
I will modify your second exaple and combine it with **slosd**'s:

```
try
{
    if (!$f = fopen(...)) throw new Exception('Error opening file!');
} 
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage() . ' ' . $e->getFile() . ' at line ' . $e->getLine;
}
echo ' ... and the code continues ...';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own solution.  Note that it needs either a script-level global or a static variable of a class for easy reference.  I wrote it class-style for reference, but so long as it can find the array it's fine.

```
class Controller {
  static $errors = array();
}

$handle = fopen($file) or array_push(Controller::errors,
  "File \"{$file}\" could not be opened.");

 // ...print the errors in your view
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dying you could throw an exception and do the error handling centrally in whichever fashion you see fit :-)